# XPath/Scrapy crawling weirdly formatted pages

Tags: xpath, html-parsing, scrapy

I've been playing around with scrapy and I see that knowledge of xpath is vital in order to leverage scrapy sucessfully.  I have a webpage I'm trying to gather some information from where the tags are formatted as such

```
<div id = "content">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
```

Now the heading contains a title and the first 'p' contains data1 and the second 'p' contains data2. This seems like a pretty straight forward task, and if this were always the case I would have no problem i.e. `hsx.select('//*[@id="content"]')` etc. etc.

The problem is, sometimes there will only be ONE p tag following a header instead of two.

```
<div id = "content">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p> (a)
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p> (b)
  <p></p> (c)
```

What i would like is if there is a paragraph tag missing I want to store that information as just blank data in my list. Right now what happens is the lists are storing the first heading 1, the first paragraph tag(a), and then the paragraph tag under the second h1 (b).
What it should be doing is storing

```
title -> h1[0]
data1[0] -> (a)
data2[0] ->[]
```

I hope that makes sense. I've been looking for a good xpath or scrapy solution to do this but I can't seem to find one. Any helpful tips would be awesome. thanks

Comment: `//div[@id='content']//p`, then use next-sibling and/or previous-sibling to see if there's h1's before/after to determine which P you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[@id='content']
     /h1[1]/following sibling::*
             [not(position()>2)][self::p]
```

This selects the (utmost) two immediate sibling elements, only if they are `p`, of the first `h1` child of any `div` (we know that this must be just one `div) the string value of whose`id`attribute is`"content"`.

If only the first immediate sibling is a `p`, then the returned node-list contains only one item.

You can check whether the length of the returned node-list is 1 or 2, and use this to build the control of your processing.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I needed. It throws an exception when looking for a second p element and I think I can just catch the exception and deal with it then. Alternatively I think what you said is a cleaner solution to look for the length of the node-list and then build it based on that I'll probably end up doing that! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want something like this; not 100% though / untested.

```
//h1/following-sibling::*[2][self::p]/text()|//h1[not(following-sibling::*[2][self::p])]/string('')
```